# Using two Firebase services from different Firebase projects into one mobile app

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have developed an android and iOS app for client using Firebase SDK and using the Firebase Push notifications. I have used the client's Gmail account for setting up the Firebase app that has been used in the apps.

After reading about Realtime database service I am wondering to use the service in mobile app. However I don't want to maintain the real time db in client's account.

Can I use another google account for Realtime Database while the notifications will continue to work using the client's account ?

Thank you, 
Kindly share suggestions on this scenario.

Any help would be appreciated !!

Comment: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/working-with-multiple-firebase-projects-in-an-android-app.html

Comment: @DougStevenson thank you for sharing the article. It helped me to manage firebase with different accounts and different firebase projects as well in one mobile app. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes You can Use Another Gmail Account.You can create new Gmail account for firebase setup.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is possible to use a different Google Account for this scenario. Just make sure that you initialize the [FirebaseApp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp) instance to the corresponding Firebase Project to access it's DB.